# How yo open a website from iphone shortcut without url bar showing

Tags: python, java, html, css, iphone

I don't have much experience with HTML files, is it possible to edit the file in order to do this?

I tried to find an option within the browser settings to hide the toolbar but it keeps re appearing when I open the app shortcut.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is NO.
As iPhone has its own security terms and protocols. You are not able to open an url or links without showing url symbol.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can open a website from iPhone shortcut without URL bar showing by using the 3D Touch feature. To do this:

1. Open the Safari browser on your iPhone.
2. On the home page of Safari, find the website you want to open and press firmly on the icon for a few seconds until the 3D Touch menu appears.
3. Tap on the ‘Open in New Tab’ option from the 3D Touch menu. This will open the website in a new tab without the URL bar being visible.